# non-form based file upload servlet in Java

Tags: java, file, servlets, file-upload

I am trying to upload files using HTML5 File API to a Java Servlet. Here is the use case

- A user downloads the file to local file system (using HTML5 file api)
- Once, the required change is done, the file needs to be uploaded back to the server.

There is no form based selection and the file needs to be streamed. I am successful in converting files to base64 encoded string and sending to the server (which is form based upload) as a string attribute.

But, I wanted to server to accept Arraybuffer or binary streams. This is not possible in form-based based upload. So, is there any other way of handling file uploads in Java other than form-based methodologies ?

Comment: you want to edit the file and right click it and select `send`, and automatically upload it to your server?

Comment: Editing the file will save the file in local file system. Later the user will radio select the file to upload and automatically upload to the server

Comment: A solution for non-form based file upload method:
[Upload file to servlet without using HTML form](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/upload-file-to-servlet-without-using-html-form)